# GDB step until function returns error?

Tags: gdb

I have a function that calls a big chunk of code that isn't mine. I'm trying to debug it, but just stepping until it returns an error has been slow and painful.

Is there a way to break when the function is "about to" return a negative number? I think I can set a breakpoint on the return register, but I only want it for the current thread.. and ideally, it would be nice to break at "return -1;" so the stack and function variables are still readable.

(I tried using the reverse debugging, which would be perfect, but gdb 8.1 crashes when I enable reverse debugging on my ubuntu 16 system.)